# Aws EC2 (Nginx Debian) and RDS error php_network_getaddresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have Aws EC2 (Nginx Debian) and RDS, with a simple php script

```
if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
   echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
}
else {
   echo "Connected.";
}
```

sometimes get this error:

```
Not connected, error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

I have already reboot EC2, but the error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the security group of the attached to RDS? Make sure the EC2 is visible in inbound rules and outbound rules.

Comment: yes. Issue occurs suddenly, if I refresh the page like 20 times, it connects 18 times and 2 give an error